# Scaffolding through my own language (Rapid Application Development)

Tags: java, typescript, spring

I'm developing a webapp where some parts that repeat, so I made source code to generate source code.

I had a lot of fun using Spring-Roo and Grails in the past but was sad that the difference between script and template becomes mind-blowing.

So, for fun I created my own compressed language and scaffold to Typescript, Lesscss and Java.

```
/* for-loop filling a select with options */
<select>
  {{for localhost:8081/ myoptions = 
                  SELECT
                      o.name as optionname,
                      o.id as optionvalue
                  FROM
                      Options o
                  WHERE
                      o.company.id = :companyId}}
    <option value="{{optionvalue}}">{{optionname}}</option>
  {{/for}} 
</select>

{{less: 
  select {
    background: red;
  }
}}
```

The generated classes pass `pmd`, `findbugs`, `tslint` and `checkstyle` except for the documentation (jsdoc, javadoc).

The HQL can be nested. The parameter `companyId` is from an outer for-loop.

eTag, CSRF and cross-site-scripting-protection work under the hood. If I change the code the server recompiles, deploys and reloads the microservices as OSGI bundles (example using localhost as domain and port 8081) and the browser immediately refreshes the website within a second (I have a fast workstation).

The JSON from server to client looks like this:

```json
{"myoptions":[{"optionname":"Hello","optionvalue":1}]}
```

Hence my rad-code is not production-ready, but the generated Java and Typescript are.

Since this is the source source code, I'd like to review that.

Any considerations?

Comment: It seems like you're asking for a review of a section of home-grown language. Please carefully read https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10522/can-i-ask-a-question-about-a-custom-scripting-language . If we don't have access to the interpreter, then it seems unlikely we'd be able to meaningfully review this.